# react + asp.net core (.net 6) create new controller

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

When I create and use new controller,
It looks like can not approach the controller.

This is source and I creacted 'BooksController'.
And console error is 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'

```
export class BooksIndex extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            books: [],
            loading: true
        }
    }

    // page initialized
    componentDidMount() {
        this.populateBooksData();
    }

    static renderBooksTable(books) {
        return (
            <table className='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tabelLabel">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Created</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {books.map(book =>
                        <tr key={book.id}>
                            <td>{book.id}</td>
                            <td>{book.title}</td>
                            <td>{book.description}</td>
                            <td>{book.created}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

    render() {

        let content = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : BooksIndex.renderBooksTable(this.state.books);

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>My Books</h1>
                <h2>This is my book</h2>
                {content}
            </div>
        );
    }

    async populateBooksData() {
        const response = await fetch("books");
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ books: data, loading: false });
    }
}
```

cf) This is a screenshot when the project execute.
WhetherWebcaster is a controller created by default when a project is created.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQCwT.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used the react spa template via `dotnet new react`, then it's probably because of the context in the setupProxy.js in ClientApp/src which by default looks something like this:

```
const context =  [
  "/weatherforecast",
];

module.exports = function(app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};
```

You can either add `/books` to that context array or, as I would suggest, just change it to `/api` and then use this attribute on your controllers (or create a base controller that the others inherit from): `[Route("api/[controller]")]`

Comment: `/api` what a nice suggestion